# Displaying a message according to the time - code not working

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning JavaScript.
I was trying to use if statements to display an appropriate message according to the time and the switch statement to show a picture next to the message, however the code is not working:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Time of the day </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        function writeIt() {
            var date = new Date();
            var hour = date.getHours();
            var timeOfDay;
            if (hour >= 7 && hour <12) {
                document.write("Good morning");
                timeOfDay = "morning";
            }
            else if (hour >= 12 && < 18) {
                document.write("Good afternoon");
                timeOfDay = "noon";
            }
            else {
                document.write("Good night!");
                timeOfDay = "night";    
            }

            switch (timeOfDay) {
                case "morning";
                case "day":
                    document.write("<img src='/images/morning.jpg/' />")
                    break;
                case "afternoon":
                    document.write("<img src='/images/afternoon.jpg/' />")
                    break;
                default:
                    document.write("<img src='/images/night.jpg" />")
                    break;
            } 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="writeIt()">
    hello
</body>
</html>
```

So far I found out that if I remove "else if ...", the if statement works okay... Have you got any clue what might be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must treat every `if - else` expression as a standalone expression. That means that the interpreter will not understand this line:

```
else if (hour >= 12 && < 18) {
```

It will see it as "variable named *hour* is more or equal to 12 and variable named *um... wait what?* less than 18". You *are required* to treat both expressions as if they were alone or in different statements. So the right code for you is

```
else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) {
```

Which means "variable named *hour* is more or equal to 12 and variable named *hour* less than 18"

Answer (score 0):

Change `else if (hour >= 12 && < 18) {` to `else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) {`.

Comment: Oh right, yeah, you're right. I'm still wondering how I managed to miss it, was reading through the code 100 times. Thanks a lot for spotting this!

Comment: You're welcome! Just a heads up, it's good Stack Overflow etiquette to mark an answer as accepted when you find one that answers your question well. Though for the record I think Nordenheim's answer is more well fleshed out than mine.

Comment: Ok Thomas, I'm still new to StackOverflow and unsure how I can mark an answer as accepted.. I'll do this as soon as I figure out how!